# Stopping an iterator before the end

Tags: c++

I have an iterator p and a vertex curvePoints:

```
for (p = curvePoints.begin(); p != curvePoints.end(); p++) {
  p->x = (1 - u) * p->x + u * (p+1)->x;
  p->y = (1 - u) * p->y + u * (p+1)->y;
}
```

Right now the loops use the value of the next indexed object; how can I guarantee that that next value exists. In other words, how can I make the loop condition something like `(p+1) != curvePoints.end()` or `p != curvePoints.end() - 1`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OpenGL api's.

Comment: By "vertex" do you mean "vector"?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::distance(p, curvePoints.end()) > 1` as you condition.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/

Answer (score 1):

How about changing `p != curvePoints.end()` to
`(p != curvePoints.end()) && ((p + 1) != curvePoints.end())`?

Comment: It wont work if his iterator isn't a random access iterator, will it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can cache and reuse the value of `p`-s successor:

```
auto p = curvePoints.begin();
if (p != curvePoints.end()) {
  auto pn = p; ++pn;
  for (; pn != curvePoints.end(); p = pn, ++pn) {
    ... // use pn instead of (p+1)
  }
}
```

NB: Pre-increment is preferable for iterators.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to not compare against `end()` unless the sequence is empty. If the sequence is non-empty you would compare against `end() - 1` and probably cache the value:

```
for (auto p(points.begin()), 
          end(c.end() - (c.empty()? 0, 1));
     p != end; ++p) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 for (p = curvePoints.begin(); p < curvePoints.end(); p++) {
          p->x = (1 - u) * p->x + u * (p+1)->x;
          p->y = (1 - u) * p->y + u * (p+1)->y;
```

Comment: The great majority of iterators do not support `<`. But worse, this doesn't even work for the ones that do. `p<end` implies `p != end`.